# How to draw a straight line and determine the gradient from the graph?

Tags: coordinate-systems

The following gives experimental values of two variables $x$ and $y$ which are known to be connected by a relation of the form $xy=a+bx$.

So, this information was given in a table.

$x=0.4,y=22.0$

$x=0.6,y=15.3$

$x=0.8,y=12.0$

$x=1.0,y=10.0$

$x=1.2,y=8.7$

Plot a graph of $y$ against $\frac{1}{x}$ ad use it to estimate the value of $a$ and $b$.

I did plot a graph, but I did not a straight line, but still tried to make a line of best fit.  I couldn't understand then how to make lines for findind the gradient!

Can someone please help me drawing the graph and finding the gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it. Create a new data set as follows. For each data point $(x,y)$, create a new data point $(\frac{1}{x},y)$. Here are the transformed data:

$$\{(2.5, 22.), (1.66667, 15.3), (1.25, 12.), (1., 10.), (0.833333, 8.7)\}$$

Plot these data and you should find a straight line:

[image: enter description here]

The equation of this graph is $y = 7.984X + 2.023$. Since the new $X$ variable is $\frac{1}{x}$, this says $y = 7.984\frac{1}{x} + 2.023$. Multiply through by $x$ and you find
$$xy = 7.984 + 2.023x\,.$$ Thus $a \approx 7.984$ and $b \approx 2.023$.

(Are these real measurements? The linear fit is unrealistically good.)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Jason :) The answers are right, they just didn't write the numbers after the decimal points! Thank you!!!

Comment: Great, glad to help. The method works because when you divide $xy = a + bx$ by $x$, you get $y = a\frac{1}{x} + b$, which is "$y = mx + b$" but with reciprocals for the $x$-coordinates.